# Remove all quotes within values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove all double quotes within all columns and all values in a dataframe. So if I have a value such as

```
potatoes are "great"
```

I want to return

```
potatoes are great
```

DataFrame.replace() lets me do this if I know the entire value I'm changing, but is there a way to remove individual characters?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this on each Series/column using [str.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['potatoes are "great"', 'they are'])

In [12]: s
Out[12]: 
0    potatoes are "great"
1                they are
dtype: object

In [13]: s.str.replace('"', '')
Out[13]: 
0    potatoes are great
1              they are
dtype: object
```

I would be wary of doing this across the entire DataFrame, because it will also change columns of non-strings to strings, however you could iterate over each column:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].str.replace('"', '')
```

If you were sure every item was a string, you could use [applymap](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))
```

Comment: might better link to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods (with wonderful 0.13 additions!)

Comment: @Noah and (one) more in 0.13.1 - get_dummies :)

Comment: you can get still use applymap if you put a condition for handling the non string values as part of the lambda: ```df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"', '') if (isinstance(x, str)) else x) ```

Answer (score 6):

use `DataFrame.apply()` and `Series.str.replace()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

a = np.array(["".join(random.sample('abcde"', 3)) for i in range(100)]).reshape(10, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.apply(lambda s:s.str.replace('"', ""))
```

If just `string` columns:

```
df.ix[:,df.dtypes==object].apply(lambda s:s.str.replace('"', ""))
```

Comment: is there an easy way to make this inplace?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
returnlist=[]
for char in string:
    if char != '"':
         returnlist.append(char)
string="".join(returnlist)
```

Comment: Why?  How?  Code dumps are not answers.  Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it solves the problem.