# Pandas - replace a doublequote(") in a dataframe with something

Tags: python, pandas, replace, concatenation

I'm making a little project for my self, where I combine two csv-files with `pd.concat()`

As seen in the picture below, there was added double quotes to the data from each sheet i combined "data from sheet 1", "data from sheet 2"
[example from data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njqlz.png)

I want to remove the double quotes from the csv-file, but when i use:

```
 df = df.replace('"', '', regex=True)
```

nothing happens.

if I use:

```
df = df.replace('e', 'x', regex=True)
```

it works fine

Here is my code:

```html
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import os
from pathlib import Path
import csv

#path of the file we read from
filename = os.path.join('..', 'C:\\prosjekt_lisensrapport\\201902_ModulesLicensesReport.xlsx')

sheet_names = [0,1]

dfs = pd.read_excel(filename,
                sheet_name=sheet_names)

pd.concat((df.assign(source=sheet) for sheet, df in dfs.items()), ignore_index=True)

def sheets_to_df(filename, sheet_names):
    df_dict = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=sheet_names)
    return pd.concat(
        (df.assign() for sheet, df in dfs.items()), axis=1, join='inner')


    
df = sheets_to_df(filename, sheet_names)

df = df.replace('"', '', regex=True)

df.to_csv('testResult.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please print a part of your dataframe and paste here for debugging?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this but it will convert your non-string columns to string one (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21491485/3780625)):

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].str.replace('"', '')
```

If you don't care, you can use [applymap()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))
```

Or much simpler, just open the file and replace all double quotes with the char you want. No need to insert your data into a DataFrame to do this.

Best

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that still did nothing to the dataframe.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: The goal with the project is that I can easily filter out all the rows that has a positive value in specific columns, so converting all columns to string would impact that in a negative way I think.

I also tried the applymap() function, but it made no impact on the file.

Comment: Did you correctly reassign the dataframe ? I made a mistake on my post that is corrected now. And btw, why don't simple remove all the double quotes in the file instead of reading the file in a DF and then update the DF ?

Comment: I guess that is a outcome of severe tunnel vision...
A good old file.open() - replace - file.write() did the the magic :)

Thank you very much for the help here @Maxouille

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the topic as answered. I updated my answer.